# How to view a LinkedIn profile anonymously?

Tags: privacy, linkedin, profile

I saw this ad this morning:

[image: unlock-the-full-list-of-who-s-viewed-your-profile-with-linkedin-premium]

Is there really no way to avoid the awkwardness?

[This page](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/administration/customer-service/ADM_CSV/771559-21639974) describes a solution but the settings menu they are suggesting does not exist anymore.

Comment: You can browse anonymously with Firefox, Chrome or even IE9. This is not the easiest solution but at least, it's a workaround

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very similar to the link you provided:

- Under your name (top right) select **Settings**
- Under *Privacy Controls* select **Select what others see when you've viewed their profile**
- Select **You will be totally anonymous**

Comment: Thanks! I notice a contradiction between "Unlock the **full** list" in the ad and "totally anonymous" in the privacy setting...

Answer (score 0):

Could not find the way you explain in [the other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35225/354), but through help I have found a link to do it
https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49410/kw/How+to+view+a+LinkedIn+profile+anonymously

Comment: A link with no other context is not very helpful, even if it is a link to official documentation. We like answers to be self-contained.